# Colors for Red-Green Vision Deficiency feature not working in Android Studio Arctic Fox?

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

Anyone knows what happened with **Colors for Red-Green Vision Deficiency** feature in last version of Android Studio Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 2 ??

I activate the option in the Accessibility menu and restart:

[image]

But the colors remain the same, they do not change as they always changed:

[image: d]

Doesn't it work for someone else? I have a Macbook Air 2017 - Big Sur Intel i5. In previous versions of AS it worked very well for me :(

Comment: FWIW, I just tried Arctic Fox Patch 1 on Ubuntu 21.04, and the colors changed for me. One difference, beyond the OS, is that I have a light theme. Also, I have not updated to Patch 2 yet.

Comment: Tried Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 Patch 2 on a MacBook Pro running Mac OS 10.13.6 High Sierra and was able to see keyword color change from default. I am also using dark theme in IDE.